# ImportError in pandas install

Tags: python, pandas, importerror

I got the following import error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'izip_longest' from 'itertools'
> (unknown location)

I need a pandas version older than 2.0 (current) and I have this error continuously. I don't know what else to do, can anyone help me?

[image: Error Image]

I already tried to change the version of Python, pandas, and pip. But nothing was resolved. Because of a deprecated method, I cannot use the current version of Pandas.

Comment: python setup.py install

Answer (score 1):

From Pyhton3 onwards izip_longest has been depricated. Use [zip_longest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=zip_longest#itertools.zip_longest) instead

You can also refer [this](https://github.com/pycalphad/pycalphad/issues/6)

```
from itertools import zip_longest
```

it doesn't appear like a pandas specific issue. I would recommend creating a Python 3 virtual environment and then installing pandas in that environment

Comment: This problem occurs when installing pandas v1.5.3 from pip. How can I change the required module to zip_longest instead of izip_longest?